# Continuity of the sum of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous, then $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is continuous. What about the converse? Suppose I knew that a function $j(x)$ is continuous and knew that it is composed of a sum of functions. Furthermore, suppose that I can create different expressions whose sum still yield me $j(x)$. For example, let $j(x)=x^4-9x+2x^2+4$, then the possible expressions whose sum still yield me $j(x)$ would be: 
$$j(x)=k(x)+l(x)\;\;where\;\;k(x)=x^4, l(x)=-9x+2x^2+4$$
$$j(x)=m(x)+n(x)\;\;where\;\;m(x)=x^4-9x, n(x)=2x^2+4$$
And so on. Would each component of every possible expression whose sum yield me the continuous function be continuous? (Using the framework above, would $k(x), l(x),m(x),n(x)$ be continuous given that $j(x)$ is continuous?).

Comment: Yes, every possible combination that yields $j(x)$. Though I would think that it will always be true for $j(x)=j(x)+0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be ANY function, then $j(x) = 0 = f(x) + (-f(x))$ is continuous.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am not sure whether $j(x)$ is continuous or whether $f(x)$ is continuous. $j(x)$ could be such that $j(x)\neq 0$. Furthermore, I would think that the statement would not let us infer the continuity of $f(x)$. I would think that there is no guarantee that $j(x)+f(x)=-f(x)$ is continuous since we do not know whether $f(x)$ is continuous or not (assuming that this is the right interpretation). Am I missing something?

Comment: I mean, pick any $f$ (ANY, might be discontinuous), then $j = 0 = f + (-f)$ is continuous. So your conjecture is not true in general.

Comment: I see. So the answer is no. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h:\mathbf{R} \longrightarrow \mathbf{R}$ such that $h(x)=1$ for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$.

Define $f(x)=1$ for $x \in \mathbf{Q}, f(x) =0$ otherwise.

Define $g(x)=0$ for $x \in \mathbf{Q}$, $g(x)=1$ otherwise.

$h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ but are $f$ and $g$ continuous?